# Library not linking with 0.41 versions of react-native

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, react-native, react-native-ios

I'm having issues linking libraries to a react-native project even after attempting to link manually multiple different times. I've gone through a ton of "praised" tutorials with no success.

I'm not an expert in Objective-C/iOS-native, so to isolate the issue I decided to create a HelloWorld Library and a HelloWorld react-native project.

Using:

- react-native v0.41.2
- react-native-cli v2.0.1
- react-native-create-library v1.0.4
- xcode v8.2.1

I did the following:

1. `react-native-create-library Lib`.
2. `react-native init RNLibTest`.
3. "Successfully linking" (Tried both manually and `react-native link ...`)

Here is the code:

### RNLib

```
// ./ios/RNLib.h
#import <React/RCTBridgeModule.h>

@interface RNLib : NSObject <RCTBridgeModule>

@end



// ./ios/RNLib.m
#import "RNLib.h"

@implementation RNLib

RCT_EXPORT_MODULE();

RCT_EXPORT_METHOD(helloWorld:(NSString *)world)
{
  return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"hello %@", world];
}

@end



// ./index.js
import { NativeModules } from 'react-native';

const { RNLib } = NativeModules;
console.log(RNLib); // undefined
console.log(NativeModules); // Object: RNLib NOT included

export default RNLib;
```

### HelloWorld / RNLibTest

```
// index.ios.js

import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { AppRegistry, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import RNLib from 'react-native-lib'; // I installed RNLib with npm and then "linked".

export default class RNLibTest extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    console.log(RNLib); // undefined
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Text>Hello World</Text>
        <Text>{
          RNLib.helloWorld("world") 
          /* throws error "can't read property helloWorld of undefined" */
        }</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

AppRegistry.registerComponent('RNLibTest', () => RNLibTest);
```

### My questions:

1. If the code is not wrong, could it be the xcode project created by react-create-native-library somehow not working with newer versions of react-native?
2. Is anyone else having these issues? If so, what did you do to fix it?
3. If you haven't encountered this issue, are you using the latest version of react-native?
4. What version are you using of xcode, react-native-cli, etc...?
5. Did anyone have to downgrade to fix this issue?

---

### UPDATE Feb/22/2017

There is a new release of react-native-create-library (v1.1.0) that supports v0.40+. I tried again and updated the code above, but I'm still seeing the same issue.

[Here is a link to the GitHub issue](https://github.com/frostney/react-native-create-library/issues/27#issuecomment-281211376). I also uploaded [react-native-lib library](https://github.com/pgarciacamou/react-native-lib) and [LibTest app](https://github.com/pgarciacamou/LibTest) to GitHub.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what caused the issue but with react-native 0.42 out, I decided to try again.

Same code, same libraries, same everything BUT react-native 0.42, these were my results:

1. using `react-native link` => WORKED.
2. using manual installation => WORKED.

I'm not sure what happened in 0.41 but it is not happening in 0.42!

[image]

Comment: Gah.  Weird.  I am seeing this same issue with 0.50.0 and 0.51.0.  I haven’t tried 0.42 yet though

Answer (score 0):

Not Sure Whether `react-native-create-library` support 0.41 RN But from the code i could say you need to import `RCT*h` files like `<React/RCTBridgeModule.h>`

Since this is single fine you can create a `RNLib.h` File in Xcode and check you would get compile time error

Thanks

Comment: I just tried downloading the Sample Library from [react-native source](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/tree/master/Libraries/Sample) and it didn't work either.

Comment: I updated the code as per your request and still no success.